# How adding redundant true conditions to where clause improves the Hive query performance?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

Let me demonstrate with an example. We have a table with 1 million records with several columns. Notice the dt condition in the where clause.

```
create table tbl as
select * from some_table
where dt > '20200601'
limit 1000000;
```

Now, if I use the Hive `explain` command to get the execution plan for my sample query I get following results:

```
explain
select id from tbl
where 
    id > 1000; 

Stage-0
  Fetch Operator
    limit:-1
    Stage-1
      Map 1
      File Output Operator [FS_3]
        Select Operator [SEL_2] (rows=333333 width=196)
          Output:["_col0"]
          Filter Operator [FIL_4] (rows=333333 width=196)
            predicate:(rid > 1000L)
            TableScan [TS_0] (rows=1000000 width=196)
              user@tbl,tbl, ACID table,Tbl:COMPLETE,Col:NONE,Output:["id"]
```

The optimizer reports returning 333k records for select. If I add another *Where* condition on another column, which I know will be true anyway, optimizer reports much smaller number for the SELECT query.

```
explain
select id from tbl
where 
    id > 1000; 
    AND dt > '20200601';

Stage-0
  Fetch Operator
    limit:-1
    Stage-1
      Map 1
      File Output Operator [FS_3]
        Select Operator [SEL_2] (rows=111111 width=196)
          Output:["_col0"]
          Filter Operator [FIL_4] (rows=111111 width=196)
            predicate:((id > 1000L) and (dt > '20200601'))
            TableScan [TS_0] (rows=1000000 width=196)
              user@tbl,tbl, ACID table,Tbl:COMPLETE,Col:NONE,Output:["id","dt"]
```

For the queries that I use day to day in work I tested this situation, and often (not always) adding another more conditions to *Where* clause reduces the number of the Select operator in the execution plan. 
I work with tables of few billion records, and any optimization of query is good news to me.

How should I interpret this reduction in select operator numbers in Explain command?

- Does it mean that adding a dummy where condition (that shows a
  reduction with Explain command) can potentially improve the query
  performance?
- Beside the readability and style, is there any
  downsides to adding such dummy conditions to Where clause, can it
  actually hurt the query performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figures in the plan is taken from the statistics whiich can be stale or absent at all. In case statistics is absent, the number of rows is estimated and this estimation is not accurate. Hive just estimates that all WHERE conditions are selective.

Try to [gather statistics for COLUMNS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE) and check the plan again, figures may change. 
Also make sure statistics usage is switched on before executing EXPLAIN:

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;    --this can be expensive
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true; --this can be expensive
```

Anyway these figures in the plan is an estimation based on statistics and files size, estimated average record size, not real counts, so they will rarely be 100% accurate. Files can be compressed and compression ratio is also estimated in this case.

In your simple query the number of rows estimated does not affect the query DAG and performance.

Statistics can affect DAG for complex queries and for example if Hive wrongly estimate the number of rows and will run map-join for table which does not fit in memory, then it will result in OOM, or suboptimal plan will be generated.

Dummy condition in your case does not really improves performance, just check the execution time of both queries and you will see.